# Insertar en base de datos MySQL usando Web Service PHP PDO

Tags: php, mysql, webservice, pdo, wsdl

Estoy desarrollando un Web Service PHP para consultar e insertar datos en una base de datos.
Hasta este momento, el web service es capaz de buscar registros en la tabla, sin embargo no es capaz de *insertarlos*.
Solo son tres archivos php.

El primero es `dbconn.php`

```
<?php

$host         = "localhost";
$username     = "root";
$password     = "";
$dbname       = "iesatickets";

try {
    $dbconn = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=iesatickets', $username, $password);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    print "Error!: " . $e->getMessage() . "<br/>";
    die();
}

?>
```

El segundo es el modelo para el servidor del webservice.

```
<?php
 require_once('dbconn.php');
 require_once('lib/nusoap.php'); 
 $server = new nusoap_server();

/* Fetch 1 ticket data */
function fetchTicketData($idticket){
    global $dbconn;
    $sql = "select id, title, description, project_id, tecnico_id from ticket where title = :idticket";
  // prepare sql and bind parameters
    $stmt = $dbconn->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bindParam(':idticket', $idticket);
    // insert a row
    $stmt->execute();
    $data = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    return json_encode($data);
    $dbconn = null;
}

/* Insert Ticket data */
function insertTicketData($idticket){
    global $dbconn;
    $sql_insert = "insert into ticket (id, title, description, tecnico_id) values (:idticket, :nombreTicket, :descripcionTicket, :tecnicotick)";
    $stmt = $dbconn->prepare($sql_insert);
    // insert a row
    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->execute(array(':id'=>$idticket, ':title'=>$nombreTicket, ':description'=>$descripcionTicket, ':tecnico_id'=>$tecnicotick));
    if($result) {
        echo "Your ticket has been posted";

        }
    else {
        echo "Something went wrong. Please try again.";
        }

    $dbconn = null;
}
$server->configureWSDL('ticketServer', 'urn:ticket');
$server->register('fetchTicketData',
            array('idticket' => 'xsd:string'),  //parameter
            array('data' => 'xsd:string'),  //output
            'urn:ticket',   //namespace
            'urn:ticket#fetchTicketData' //soapaction
            );  
$server->service(file_get_contents("php://input"));

?>
```

Y finalmente el cliente, donde busco e inserto.

```
<?php


      ini_set('display_errors', true);
      error_reporting(E_ALL); 


    require_once('lib/nusoap.php');
    $error  = '';
    $result = array();
    $wsdl = "http://localhost/wstickets/webservice-server.php?wsdl";

    if(isset($_POST['sub'])){
        $idticket = trim($_POST['idticket']);
        if(!$idticket){
            $error = 'idticket cannot be left blank.';
        }

        if(!$error){
            $client = new nusoap_client($wsdl, true);
            $err = $client->getError();
            if ($err) {
                echo '<h2>Constructor error</h2>' . $err;
                exit();
            }
             try {
                $result = $client->call('fetchTicketData', array($idticket));
                $result = json_decode($result);
              }catch (Exception $e) {
                echo 'Caught exception: ',  $e->getMessage(), "\n";
             }
        }
    }

    if(isset($_POST['insert'])){
        $idticket = $_POST['idticket'];
        $nombreTicket = $_POST['nameticket'];
        $descripcionTicket = $_POST['descriptionticket'];
        $tecnicotick = $_POST['tecnicoticket'];
        if(!$idticket){
            $error = 'The ID cannot be left blank.';
        }
        if(!$nombreTicket){
            $error = 'The title cannot be left blank.';
        }
        if(!$descripcionTicket){
            $error = 'The description cannot be left blank.';
        }
        if(!$tecnicotick){
            $error = 'The technicians ID cannot be left blank.';
        }
        if(!$error){
            $client = new nusoap_client($wsdl, true);
            $err = $client->getError();
            if ($err) {
                echo '<h2>Constructor error</h2>' . $err;
                exit();
            }
             try {
                $result = $client->call('insertTicketData', array($idticket));
                $result = json_decode($result);
              }catch (Exception $e) {
                echo 'Caught exception: ',  $e->getMessage(), "\n";
             }
        }
    }

?>

    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
      <title>IESATickets Web Service</title>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>

    <div class="container">
      <h2>Webservice para IESATickets</h2>
      <p>Ingrese el <strong>número de ticket</strong> para obtener la información <strong>presionando el botón de</strong> obtener.</p>
      <br />       
      <div class='row'>
        <form class="form-inline" method = 'post' name='form1'>
            <?php if($error) { ?> 
                <div class="alert alert-danger fade in">
                    <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</a>
                    <strong>Error!</strong>&nbsp;<?php echo $error; ?> 
                </div>
            <?php } ?>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="email">ID:</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" name="idticket" id="idticket" placeholder="Ingrese ID">
            </div>
            <br>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="email">Nombre</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" name="nameticket" id="nameticket" placeholder="Ingrese ID">
            </div>
            <br>        
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="email">Descripción</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" name="descriptionticket" id="descriptionticket" placeholder="Ingrese ID">
            </div>
            <br>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="email">Técnico Asignado</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" name="tecnicoticket" id="tecnicoticket" placeholder="Ingrese ID">
            </div>  
            <button type="submit" name='sub' class="btn btn-default">Buscar</button>
            <button type="submit" name='insert' class="btn btn-default">Insertar</button>
        </form>
       </div>
       <br />
       <h2>Información del Ticket</h2>
      <table class="table">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Título</th>
            <th>Descripción</th>
            <th>Título</th>
            <th>Título</th>
            <th>Título</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <?php if(count($result)){ 
                for ($i=0; $i < count($result); $i++) { ?>
                  <tr>
                    <td><?php echo $result->id; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $result->title; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $result->description; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $result->project_id; ?></td> 
                    <td><?php echo $result->tecnico_id; ?></td>
                  </tr>
          <?php 
                }
            }else{ ?>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan='5'>Ingrese el ID del ticket y el botón obtener</td>
                  </tr>
            <?php } ?>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Todo en teoría debería estar funcionando bien. Cuando presiono el botón de busqueda, sí arroja los resultados correctamente, pero cuando intento insertar, aparentemente los inserta, pero al verificar la base de datos, o con el mismo webservice, me encuentro con que no insertó nada.
¿Qué estoy haciendo mal?

La estructura de la tabla `ticket` es la siguiente:
`id`, `title`, `description` y `tecnico_id`.

Comment: Tienes dos `execute`, uno vacío: `$stmt->execute();` y otro con los parámetros más abajo de ese. Deberías probar a quitar el `execute` vacío, pues es muy probable que te lance un error ahí y el programa no se siga ejecutando hasta llegar  al `execute` correcto que es este: `$result = $stmt->execute(array(':id'=>$idticket, ':title'=>$nombreTicket, ':description'=>$descripcionTicket, ':tecnico_id'=>$tecnicotick));` Ya cuando funcione, considera verificar primero si el registro no es duplicado antes de insertar.

Comment: He verificado que el registro no es duplicado, y he eliminado el `execute` vacío que comentaste.
Aún así no inserta nada.

Comment: Revisa mi respuesta. Los marcadores de nombre deben ser exactamente iguales y no tienen nada que ver con los nombres de las variables. Tú al parececer intentaste ponerlos como se llaman las variables en la instrucción SQL, pero en el `execute` correcto usas otros marcadores. Los marcadores de nombre son para decirle al manejador a qué corresponde cada cosa. Si en una parte lo pones de una forma y en otra parte de otra, el manejador se pierde, no sabe a qué corresponde qué.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tu función **`insertTicketData`** tiene dos problemas:

- Estás ejecutando dos veces, en una no le mandas nada y es seguro que el código fallará en esa línea
- En el segundo `execute`, que debería ser el correcto, los nombres de llave del array no coinciden con los **marcadores de `:nombre`**  que usaste en la consulta preparada. Esos nombres deben ser exactamente iguales y ojo, eso no tiene nada que ver con los nombres de las columna o de las varaibles, aunque por lo general se usan los mismos nombres de columna. Lo importante ahí es que **uses los mismos marcadores en la consulta preparada y en el array**.

Corrige tu función así:

```
function insertTicketData($idticket){
    global $dbconn;
    /*
       *Aquí, todos los marcadores que uses con :nombre
       *deben ser los mismos en el array que pasas en el exectue
       *usaré los nombres de columna, para menos confusión
       *Esos marcadores no tienen nada que ver por cómo se llamen las variables
    */
    $sql_insert = "insert into ticket (id, title, description, tecnico_id) values (:id, :title, :description, :tecnico_id)";
    $stmt = $dbconn->prepare($sql_insert);
    // insert a row
    //$stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->execute(array(':id'=>$idticket, ':title'=>$nombreTicket, ':description'=>$descripcionTicket, ':tecnico_id'=>$tecnicotick));
    if($result) {
        echo "Your ticket has been posted";

        }
    else {
        echo "Something went wrong. Please try again.";
        }

    $dbconn = null;
}
```

El *quid* de la cuestión es que, si escribes una consulta así:

```
insert into 
    ticket (
                id, 
                title, 
                description, 
                tecnico_id
            ) values (
                :id, 
                :title, 
                :description, 
                :tecnico_id
            )
```

En el `execute` los nombres que uses en el array deben coincidir con cada marcador de nombre:

```
array(
        ':id'=>$idticket, 
        ':title'=>$nombreTicket,
        ':description'=>$descripcionTicket, 
        ':tecnico_id'=>$tecnicotick
    )
```

Arriba, en el marcador de nombre tú puedes poner lo que sea, por ejemplo: `:pepe` en lugar de `:id`, pero si haces eso, en el array tienes que poner también `:pepe` y no `:id`.

Comment: he corregido el código tal como tú lo has mandado y no ha funcionado.

Comment: ¿es posible que la haya regado en el lado del cliente?

Comment: @JosueMarin pero qué hace, te devuelve este mensaje: *`Something went wrong. Please try again`*?

Comment: Otra cosa que noto ahora es que ninguna de las variables que intentas insertar existen en el ámbito de la función, excepto `$idticket` que es recibida en parámetro, pero ¿de dónde sacas el valor de las otras?

Comment: no, no devuelve ningún mensaje, eso es lo más raro.
Y además, intenté adaptar el código que se muestra [acá](http://www.w3programmers.com/soap-with-php-and-mysql/) (el comentario del usuario JITEN CHOUDHARY)

Comment: Y el código de consulta está ligeramente basado en el tutorial que se encuentra [acá](https://neurocodigo.wordpress.com/2012/10/07/webservice-con-phpmysqlnusoap-ii/)

Comment: Las variables no existen en el ámbito de la función... ¿de dónde sacas su valor?  La función sólo recibe una variable en parámetro... ¿y las otras?

Comment: Se supone que las envío por medio de POST a la función. O eso fue lo que entendí de los vídeos.

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/85356/discussion-between-a-cedano-and-josue-marin).

Comment: No es correcto. Estamos hablando de una función definida así: `function insertTicketData($idticket){` ... significa que cuando llamas a esa función debes pasarle los datos con los que ella va a trabajar. En este caso la función está habilitada para recibir un solo dato, debes cambiar su definición, agregando los otros valores que ella necesita para trabajar...

Comment: te he mandado algo en el chat.

Comment: @JosueMarin disculpa. ¿Al final resolviste el problema?